# Displaying a Carrierwave filename in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave

I am trying to display the filename of a Carrierwave attachment in a Rails erb template. The following does not work:

```
<%= @page.form.filename %>
```

This seems in line with [the documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.5.2/CarrierWave/SanitizedFile#filename-instance_method). Is some additional step needed?

My page model looks like this:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :form, FormUploader

end
```

The form uploader looks like this:

```
class FormUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(pdf)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 81, accepted):

The documentation you're looking at is the sanitized file, it's what it uses for actually storing a file. The part you're looking for is FormUploader, which is an Uploader, and part of http://rubydoc.info/gems/carrierwave/0.5.2/CarrierWave/Uploader

If you want to get the file name, you could either read it from the database column directly, or use `File.basename(@page.form.path)` to extract it easily.

Comment: you should use path instead of url, using url with aws or another cloud provider will include querystrings

Comment: Only if you're using signed URLs, I've corrected it to paths though.

Comment: Just thought I would say, that if you are using a mounted uploader named image in the images table you would get to the basename like this Image.first.image.file.basename it tripped me up a little while first investigating this. I was trying to use Image.first.image.basename which is not valid.

Comment: Not sure how I accidentally downvoted this answer, but if @Zachary Anker would edit it I could upvote it.

Comment: Hmm why is it better than Kikito answer `@page.form.file.filename` ?

Answer (score 87):

I have been able to get the filename via the `file` internal parameter:

```
<%= @page.form.file.filename %>
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest answer to the OP's question.

Comment: This only appears to work if the filename method is explicitly set in the uploader class.

Comment: This is the best answer to OP's question

Comment: This looks like the best way to me - why operate on the full path string with File.basename ? Seems like an extra step :)

Comment: hi i have problem, method `.file` is undefined

Comment: @JaisAnasrullohJa'fari my answer was from 2012. Things have probably changed since then. Good luck!

Answer (score 17):

The [Carrierwave docs](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#activerecord) might be a bit off, but recommended way seems to be:

```
@page.form.file.identifier
```

Comment: @cheng try `@page.form.file_identifier`

Answer (score 9):

@adamonduty's solution is great. Another solution I used before, just create a method on the model:

```
def name
  file.path.split("/").last
end
```

Comment: This is most reliable in my experience :)

Comment: beware: this wont work on platforms with a path separator other than "/"

Answer (score 6):

You're right @epylinkn. Documentation points towards using:

```
@page.form.file.identifier
```

But when I use that, I always get `nil` (just as @Cheng commented).

I then inspected my objects methods (`@page.form.file.methods.inspect`), and found the following to work:

```
@page.form.file_identifier
```

Comment: yes, the working method is `xxx_identifer`.  underscore + url, underscore + identifier, etc... is the syntax form adopted for the methods

Answer (score 6):

In your model's associated uploader class, define a filename method.

```
def filename
  File.basename(path)
end
```

You can then call

```
model_instance.file.filename
```

Works as of CarrierWave 1.1.0.  This is a succinct restatement/amalgamation of kikito and Chris Alley's responses above.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using ActiveRecord, you can directly access the field named `form` in two ways:

```
def my_method
  self[:form]
end
```

or

```
def my_method
  form_before_type_cast
end
```

The second method is read-only.

Comment: The other solutions fail when there is no uploaded file. `user['avatar']` will return the filename or `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

`CarrierWave::SanitizedFile` has a private `original_filename` method containing the filename of the uploaded file. (docs: http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/carrierwave/master/CarrierWave/SanitizedFile:original_filename)

After reading through [this thread from the CarrierWave mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/carrierwave/browse_thread/thread/bce92c339bc2e882), none seemed to fit my needs. With something like

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
  # ...
```

I heavily modify the `:file` column value from the original filename. Due to this I decided to track the original filename in a separate column from the one bound to CarrierWave. In my `FileUploader` I simply added a reader that wraps the private `original_filename` method:

```
def original_file
  original_filename
end
```

I then added a `before_create` event to the `Upload` class *(my `Upload` records are never modified, so a `before_create` is acceptable for my needs)*

```
before_create do
  self.original_file = self.file.original_file
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you've got models like this?

```
class Page
  mount_uploader :form, FormUploader
end
```

If so you should be able to call:

```
@page.form.url
@page.form.filename
```

Are you sure you've uploaded/attached the file correctly?  What do you see when you inspect @page.form?  Remember, the attachment will not be saved until you've fully processed the upload.

Comment: The attachment is saving fine. I've updated my question with the model and uploader code. Don't worry, zanker's answer fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
  before_save :update_file_attributes


  def update_file_attributes
    if file.present? && file_changed? 
      self.content_type = file.file.content_type
      self.file_size = file.file.size
      self.file_name = read_attribute(:file)
    end
  end
```