# Images not associated properly (carrier wave, fog, heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, carrierwave, fog

Trying to add carrier wave based image uploading to my user model. This works locally in development. On heroku, the image is uploaded to my s3 bucket, but never displayed. In the console, it looks like no image was uploaded.

If the image is making it to s3, why isn't it being associated properly?

Here's the code:

```
# config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
CarrierWave.configure do |config|

  if Rails.env.production?
    config.fog_credentials = {
      provider:              'AWS',               # required
      aws_access_key_id:     ENV['S3_KEY'],       # required
      aws_secret_access_key: ENV['S3_SECRET']     # required
    }

    config.fog_directory  = ENV['S3_BUCKET']      # required
    config.fog_public     = false                 # optional, defaults to true
    config.fog_attributes = {
      'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'
    }

    config.storage = :fog
  else
    config.storage = :file
  end

end

# app/uploaders/profile_picture_uploader.rb
class ProfilePictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{ model_name }/#{ mounted_as }/#{ model.id }"
  end

  def cache_dir
     Rails.root.join *%w[ tmp uploads model_name ]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w[ jpg jpeg gif png ]
  end

private

  def model_name
    @model_name ||= model.class.to_s.underscore
  end

end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :profile_picture, ProfilePictureUploader

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_picture

end

# app/views/users/edit.html.haml
%h1 Edit user

= form_for @user do |f|

  %h2 Profile Picture
  - if f.object.profile_picture.present?
    = image_tag f.object.profile_picture
    %p= f.object.profile_picture.file.basename

    = f.check_box :remove_profile_picture
    = f.label :remove_profile_picture, 'Delete your Profile Picture'

    = f.label :profile_picture, 'Replace your Profile Picture'
  - else
    = f.label :profile_picture, 'Add your Profile Picture'
  = f.file_field :profile_picture

  %p
    = f.submit 'Save'
    or
    = link_to 'cancel', @user
```

Platform:

- rails 3.1.0
- carrierwave 0.5.7
- heroku cedar stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not entirely sure *why* this works, but I added a method to my model

```
def profile_picture_file_name
  read_attribute :profile_picture_file
end
```

and use that method in my view instead of

```
f.object.profile_picture.file.basename
```

And everything is happy now.

Thanks to [Displaying a Carrierwave filename in the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132847/displaying-a-carrierwave-filename-in-the-view/5778668#5778668).