# Get file and filename from carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I successfully uploaded a file to S3 and now I want to attach file to email, so i can send it by using Gmail API. Some people suggested to call method `.file` directly like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132847/displaying-a-carrierwave-filename-in-the-view/10483434)

as you can see, you can call method

```
<%= @page.form.file.filename %>
```

`.file` directly from form.

here is my `mount uploader` class:

```
class Crm::LogEmailAttachment < Asset
    belongs_to :owner, class_name: 'Crm::LogEmail'
    mount_uploader :data, Crm::LogEmailAttachmentUploader
    mount_base64_uploader :data, Crm::LogEmailAttachmentUploader
    # default_scope -> {order("assets.order")}

    def to_s
      self.data.try(:file).try(:filename)
    end
end
```

and here is my erb form:

```
<div class="document-wrap">
   <%= log_email.fields_for :crm_log_email_attachments do |a| %>
    <%= a. file_field :data, input_html: {class: "form-control" , wrapper: 'field'}, label: false %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

then I try to get file by just calling `.file` from `params[:data]` it returns undefined method `file` for `#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc337322290>`, my question is how can I get the path of the file and filename from `carrierwave` ?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of referencing the params ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile object, you should save the data to S3 via carrierwave first, then reference the uploader object directly.  For instance

```
object.data.file.filename
```

To retrieve the filename, and

```
object.data.url
```

To retrieve the S3 URL for the associated asset.

Comment: Sorry to revive such an old question, but, how do you reference the object? Is the name you setup in the mount line?